# How to ignore specific data for table that is using angular ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have gitignore in one of my log directory now i wanted to display all the file names from that directory but `.gitignore` is also displaying how can i ignore that file using `ng-repeat` for table and display rest of the files ?

main.html

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="file in filename_data">
        <td>{{ file }}</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="downloadServerFile(file)">download</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

ctrl.js

```
$scope.filename_data = [".gitignore","server.log","server1.log"];
```

Comment: How are you populating `$scope.filename_data`? if it's really a static array like you've said, just remove `.gitignore`.

Comment: filenames are coming from backend , remove ?

Comment: Can you have the backend exclude `.gitignore`? Or just filter the array when you receive it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several options:

1. You can move `.gitignore` file to the root and specify path to you folder inside your `.gitignore`;
2. You can create a Angular's custom filter and drop away filenames started with `.`

Like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="file in filename_data | myfilter">
```

Take a look at this [article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-custom-angularjs-filters). But be careful with modifying arrays in angular's filters. It's perhaps a bad idea

**Updated**:

3. Of course you can use es5's native filter for array:

JS:

```
$scope.filename_data = $scope.filename_data.filter(function(value){
  return value.indexOf('.') !== 0;
})
```

[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) you can find the docs

Comment: cannot move .gitignore has to be there in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Filter the array before you start looping over it.

```
arr = [".gitignore","server.log","server1.log"].filter(x => x != '.gitignore')
```